# Niftynet: autocontext_mr_ct_model_zoo error: Unknown keywords in config file

Tags: niftynet

I have just started exploring NiftyNet.I am getting the following error when I try to run the `autocontext_mr_ct_model_zoo`.

When I run the following command:

```
  python net_regress.py train \   -c ~/niftynet/extensions/autocontext_mr_ct/net_autocontext.ini \  
 --starting_iter 0 --max_iter 500*
```

I get the following error message:

> ValueError: Unknown keywords in config file: [error_map] -- all  possible choices are ['', u'loss_border', 'output', 'image', 'weight', 'sampler', u'cuda_devices', u'num_threads', u'num_gpus', u'model_dir', u'dataset_split_file', u'name', u'activation_function', u'batch_size', u'decay', u'reg_type', u'volume_padding_size', u'window_sampling', u'queue_length', u'multimod_foreground_type', u'histogram_ref_file', u'norm_type', u'cutoff', u'foreground_type', u'normalisation', u'whitening', u'normalise_foreground_only', u'weight_initializer', u'bias_initializer', u'weight_initializer_args', u'bias_initializer_args', u'optimiser', u'sample_per_volume', u'rotation_angle', u'rotation_angle_x', u'rotation_angle_y', u'rotation_angle_z', u'scaling_percentage', u'random_flipping_axes', u'lr', u'loss_type', u'starting_iter', u'save_every_n', u'tensorboard_every_n', u'max_iter', u'max_checkpoints', u'validation_every_n', u'validation_max_iter', u'exclude_fraction_for_validation', u'exclude_fraction_for_inference', u'inference_iter', u'save_seg_dir', u'output_interp_order', u'border', u'csv_file', u'path_to_search', u'filename_contains', u'filename_not_contains', u'interp_order', u'pixdim', u'axcodes', u'spatial_window_size'].

I'm not quite sure what I've messed up here, any advice welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the source code you downloaded is out-of-date, are you running the command with the latest version of NiftyNet?

The pip package is slightly out-of-date at the moment, 
you could have the latest source code by running

```
git clone https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet.git

# installing dependencies from the list of requirements
cd NiftyNet/
pip install -r requirements-gpu.txt

# run command from the source code folder
python net_regress.py train \
  -c ~/niftynet/extensions/autocontext_mr_ct/net_autocontext.ini \
  --starting_iter 0 --max_iter 500
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The version I'm using now is niftynet 0.2.2, but I still get the same error at runtime. Do I need to use the latest version to download the  network weights and examples data again? Or where can I find manually downloaded links?

Comment: sorry for the confusion, I've edited the answer for the commands

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have already solved the problem

Comment: The  examples datas  of  autocontext_mr_ct_model_zoo are 2-D ,but my own datas are 3D.Is this model suitable for 3D images?If yes, what parameters do I need to change?  Thank you very much.

Comment: Please find a 3d config example here:https://github.com/NifTK/NiftyNet/blob/dev/config/default_monomodal_regression.ini (mainly changing the `spatial_window_size`)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer，Where can I download the examples data of default_monomodal_regression?